# Differences between jpg and jpeg - tif and tiff in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, jpg

I'm running QGIS 2.18.21 but this has been an issue in a few versions; is there any reason why QGIS offers both jpg and jpeg as well as tiff and tif options to export images?
Apart from being annoying (I've exported many files twice because the browser set to jpg doesn't show existing jpeg files) is there any good reason for these options?

Comment: These options exist in 3.4.0. The md5sums of the exported files are the same.

Comment: TIFF and JPEG are standards-based file formats. `.tif` and `.jpg` are conventional file suffixes. The distinction between the two is not as obvious as it should be to some, including those contributing to software source trees.

Comment: The reason is obviously that .tiff and .tif are both valid and commonly used extensions for TIFF files, as well as .jpeg and .jpg for JPEG files. For the latter also .jpe, .jif, .jfif, and .jfi could be used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

The file formats are the same.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424399/jpg-vs-jpeg-image-formats

But I guess there is no reason why the JPG format couldn't show JPEG files as well.

You can make a bug report: https://issues.qgis.org/issues

But I would expect this to be a low priority fix.